# Display the parent of child taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Here my code displays all the taxonomies with the name "Position"
How do I get to display the parent of the child taxonomies?

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'position' );

if(!empty($terms)) {
   foreach($terms as $term) {     
      $typeTaxonomy =  $term->slug . ' ';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.
Let's get the parent id of the taxonomy and display the parent taxonomy from the id.

```
  <?php 
                                    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'position' );

                                    if(!empty($terms)) {
                                        foreach($terms as $term) {  
                                            $parentId = $term->parent;
                                            if($parentId != 0)  {
                                            $taxParent = get_term($parentId, 'position') -> slug;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                $taxParent = '';
                                            }
                                            print_r($taxParent);

                                                $typeTaxonomy =  $term->slug . ' ';

                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
```